# UITabBar : edit "more" screen and rotate

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I use a `UITabBar` in my iPad application. It has a dozen of tabs, so the "More..." button is visible. When I :

1. click on the "More..." button
2. click on the "Edit" button in order to customize my tabs
3. rotate the tablet

The "Edit" screen does not rotate correctly and I got an ugly display :

[image]

Has anyone encountered the same bug ? I use only the standard iOS component `UITabBarController`, did I miss something in its configuration, or is it an iOS bug ?

Comment: I have tried it ... yes it does not change the orientation in the edit view but haven't find anything as per your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently an iOS bug.
I've created a minimalist UITabBar project with XCode wizard. Added 10 tab bars in the project, and I can reproduce the bug.
I won't try to fix this as I don't want to mess with UITabBar code or override the classes.